# In zsh, how can I more quickly disown the foreground process?

Tags: zsh, signals, background-process, disown

My method for disowning the foreground process takes too much effort.

Suppose I have a process in `zsh`'s foreground. I want to `disown` it, so I can close the shell without the process being sent a `SIGHUP`.

At the moment, I start with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to background and pause the process, then

```
$ disown
disown: warning: job is suspended, use `kill -CONT -32240' to resume
$ kill -CONT -32240
$
```

—*then* I can close the terminal.

How can I automate that? Ideally, I'd like to be able to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> or something to immediately disown the running process. Or second best, I'd want to be able to run a single command to both disown and `SIGCONT` the process once it's suspended.

Comment: It is easier to `bg`+`disown` instead of `kill -CONT -1234`.

Comment: I used to use `alias dr='disown -r'` in bash.  `bg` and `dr` do the trick.

Answer (score 16):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in a terminal, this causes the foreground process group to receive the signal SIGTSTP (assuming the terminal is in cooked mode and the default key bindings are in place). If the process hasn't set a signal handler for SIGTSTP, this causes the process to be suspended (and even if the process has set a signal handler, it usually only does a small amount of processing before suspending itself). When a process is killed, suspended or resumed, its parent is notified via a SIGCHLD signal; this is what causes the shell to display a new prompt and maybe a message like `[1] + 1234 suspended foo`. The information flow is
    key → suspension → shell
and not
    key → shell → suspension
so you can't configure a different reaction for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

You can set a trap for SIGCHLD, but the trap is not executed when the job is the current foreground job. For the most part, this means that the trap is executed only when a background job terminates, not when the foreground job terminates. But it also means that you can't react to the suspension of the foreground job.

You can indirectly react to changes in background jobs by setting a `precmd` hook that compares the job states with states saved from the previous `precmd` run. But I don't know what you could do with that: there can only be a single suspend key, so you need some extra information to know whether the process was meant to be paused, backgrounded or disowned.

I've set up zsh so that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> at an empty prompt backgrounds the current job. This lets me press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> twice to put the foreground job into the background with only a short suspension.

```
fancy-ctrl-z () {
  if [[ $#BUFFER -eq 0 ]]; then
    bg
    zle redisplay
  else
    zle push-input
  fi
}
zle -N fancy-ctrl-z
bindkey '^Z' fancy-ctrl-z
```

You could make it call `disown` if you like. Or you could arrange for a third <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to call `disown` with the following untested modification.

```
fancy-ctrl-z () {
  if [[ $#BUFFER -eq 0 ]]; then
    if (($fancy_ctrl_z_already_bg)); then
      disown
    else
      bg
      fancy_ctrl_z_already_bg=1
    fi
    zle redisplay
  else
    zle push-input
  fi
}
zle -N fancy-ctrl-z
bindkey '^Z' fancy-ctrl-z
fancy_ctrl_z_precmd () {
  fancy_ctrl_z_already_bg=0
}
precmd_functions+=fancy_ctrl_z_precmd
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the full _cooked_ mode for ^Z to work. `isig` is enough (even without `icanon`)

Comment: So the `SIGTSTP` is sent by the terminal emulator? Is it possible to configure the emulator (any that you know) to change what it does for a `^Z`? Like in the shortcut preference?

Comment: @FranklinYu The terminal emulator sends SIGTSTP when you press Ctrl+Z while a program is running and the feature is activated in the terminal interface (`stty +isig`). You can change which character triggers this with the stty command (you can't set an arbitrary key, it has to be a single byte, not an escape sequence). While the shell is in the foreground, it changes the terminal settings to take over key presses so the effect of Ctrl+Z depends on the shell's key bindings.

Comment: It's not the terminal emulator that sends the signal, it's the kernel (the tty driver, or tty line discipline that is attached to the serial or pty device). All the terminal device does is sending byte 26 when you press Ctrl+Z

Answer (score 14):

Having a global keybind to disown the foreground process is impossible: Keystrokes are received by the foreground process, not by the shell. You need to first suspend it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> if you want to disown it.

However, turns out there's a zsh option to speed up *disowning then continuing*: With `setopt AUTO_CONTINUE`, `disown` will automatically also send `SIGCONT`.

So you can get it down to `C-z` `disown`.

Answer (score 2):

For the second best, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> then typing a combination of `%` and `&|`

```
$ %&|
```

will disown the process without needing to `SIGCONT` it.

From [zshbuiltins(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins) [ellipses added]:

> ```
> SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS
>        …
>        disown [ job ... ]
>        job ... &|
>        job ... &!
>
>               … If one of the latter two forms is used, the jobs
>               will  automatically  be  made running …
> ```

and [zshmisc(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshmisc) [ellipses added]:

> ```
> JOBS
>        …
>        A job can be referred to by … the following:
>        …
>        %string
>               The last job whose command line begins with string.
> ```

Comment: The main reason I added that description was to clarify what that `%` was, which for people not familiar with job specification would seem obscure. If you know `%` is the most recently suspended job (or most recently started in background), you're less surprised when `%&!` disowns the wrong job just because some job got suspended between the time you pressed C-Z and the time you ran `disown` or `%&!`.