# In zsh, what's the difference between &! and &|?

Tags: zsh, background-process

In my [adventures with `disown`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223432/in-zsh-how-can-i-more-quickly-disown-the-foreground-process), I also discovered that in zsh, `program &!` starts and immediately backgrounds *and disowns* the program, so you can close the shell without the program getting a `SIGHUP`.

Other online sources said `&|` does this. My crude tests found no difference.

How do `&!` and `&|` differ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out they really are equivalent, according to [`man zshbuiltins`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins) (section "disown"): simply syntactic alternatives for the same operation.

Anticlimactic…